# Относится ли math.hashcode.ru к StackOverflow?

Tags: поддержка, хэшкод

http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/ ? Можно ли туда зайти, пользуясь регистрацией здесь? Просто мета там ведет сюда.

Comment: Видимо нет. По крайней мере, зайдя туда по ссылке, себя я не обнаружил. А вы сами не пробовали?

Comment: Меня там нет, но вы пробовали нажать на мету?

Comment: Да, мета сюда ведет, наверное осталось со времен Хэшкода

Comment: Живёт себе проект, и никакая Мета ему не нужна. =) Математики!

Comment: А не поможете войти туда через блоггер?

Comment: Минутка истории. Наше сообщество началось на хешкоде (проект Николаса), но потом переместилось сюда. А математики там и остались. Хэшкод прямого отношения с SE не имеет АФАИК, так что нет, нельзя.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, я еще раз говорю: не отсюда, а через Блоггер.

Comment: @mathem что за "блоггер"? Судя по всему, сейчас можно или зарегистрироваться на самом math.hashcode.ru, либо зайти через facebook. Через google, vk или яндекс похоже зайти не получится, т.к. API этих сайтов поменялось, а на math.hashcode.ru его не обновили. См. методы входа на [странице входа](http://math.hashcode.ru/account/signin/). Никакого "блоггера" там нет, кстати.

Comment: @insolor, как это нет блогера: https://postimg.cc/CzNPKhbd ?

Comment: @mathem вот так нет: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc6iH.png